# Creating Annual Sales Tax Reports using MySQL based on a Magento 1.4.1.0 store

Tags: mysql, magento, reporting, magento-1.4

Our client has a Magento-powered store and needs the ability to create tax reports based on a specified date-range with a break down of how many much was refunded via credits.

Essentially they want a table that [looks like this](http://www.widgetsandburritos.com/test/numbers.png).

To save time, and since they only need these reports twice a year, I really don't want to build it within Magento. Instead, I'm opting to just create a script to search through the MySQL tables based on the date range.  I constructed what I thought should be a query to gather the necessary numbers from the database.  Since they only charge sales tax in the state of Texas, I grouped the taxed and non-taxed pieces together using the boolean expression: fi.tax_amount > 0.   I'm referencing the following tables in my query:

1. mag_sales_flat_order: used to indicate order date ranges  (identified as fo in MySQL query)
2. mag_sales_flat_invoice: table containing all the actual invoice data (identified as fi in MySQL query)
3. mag_sales_flat_creditmemo: table containing all the credit memo data (identified as fc in MySQL query)

Most of the fields seem to be okay, but I keep getting numbers showing that the credits for shipping tax exceed the shipping tax for the gross. Perhaps I'm using the wrong fields in my query or doing something else incorrectly.  Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
    fi.tax_amount > 0 as `taxed`, 
    sum(fi.grand_total) as `sales_total`,
    sum(fi.tax_amount) as `sales_tax`, 
    sum(fi.shipping_tax_amount) as `shipping_tax`, 
    sum(fc.grand_total) as `credit_total`, 
    sum(fc.tax_amount) as `credit_sales_tax`,
    sum(fc.shipping_tax_amount) as `credit_shipping_tax`    
FROM 
    `mag_sales_flat_invoice` fi 
LEFT JOIN 
    `mag_sales_flat_order` fo ON fo.entity_id = fi.order_id     
LEFT JOIN 
    `mag_sales_flat_creditmemo` fc ON fc.order_id = fi.order_id 
WHERE     
    fo.created_at <= '2010-12-31 00:00:00' AND 
    fo.created_at >= '2010-07-01 00:00:00'     
GROUP BY
    fi.tax_amount > 0
```

Does anybody have any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?  Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks!

Comment: try to visualize the report for us so we could suggest a proper way to handle it

Comment: Well I did when I referenced this: http://www.widgetsandburritos.com/test/numbers.png, but that said, I figured out my problem. There were a few issues with the query, but the main problem was I had mixed up the order on how I was doing a calculation after I had the number. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out my problem.  It wasn't the actual numbers returned from Magento I was having problems with.  I had switched the order of 2 numbers in the calculation and it got me confused.  For those interested in my solution, I've posted it here: [Annual Tax Reports based on a Magento 1.4.1.0+ store](http://www.widgetsandburritos.com/annual-tax-reports-magento-1-4-1-0-store/)

Comment: Hey David -- do you think you can put this solution up again?  the link is dead.  Perhaps if you are using 1.6+, if there are any changes that might need to be made?